# Can any vector multiplying a matrix $A$ be written as a combination of its eigen vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading, Introduction to Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang, 5th Edition. In chapter 6.2, under the section, "Matrix Powers $A^k$", the book describes Fibonacci's example using the difference equation -

$u_{k+1} = Au_{k}$

The process involves -

$A^{k}u_{0} = X\lambda^{k}X^{-1}u_0$

Then the book states -

"*Write $u_0$ as a combination of $c_1x_1 + ... + c_nx_n$ of the eigenvectors.*"

My question is how does one know that the vector $u_0$ can be written as the combination of the vectors in the matrix $X$. The above statement seems to assume that the vector $u_0$ is in the space described by the basis X. But I don't understand why that's correct.

Comment: Matrix $A$ describing the Fibonacci recursion is full rank, so $u_0$ is in the basis of its eigenvectors

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I am a little lost here. Basically, I don't see any relation between $A$ and $u_0$.

Comment: if matrix $A$ is full-rank, then every vector is in the span of its eigenvectors

Comment: You mean, if a $n  \times n$ matrix is full rank, then it spans $R^n$?

Comment: If $n\times n$ matrix is full rank, then its eigenvectors span $\mathbb{R}^n$